# Disputes about question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators, flagging

This question: [How often does a propeller vane break off?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/99525/42636) has been disputed.

To an average user, there seems to be no access whatsoever into the reasons pertaining to the dispute status. Why so?

The question in question (lol) is a fine example of a story that needs verification / debunking, and the community has quite clearly filled it's task in this sense. Thus I find it strange that the question is under dispute.

Comment: The answers broadly answer a different question than that which was asked (with some exception - actually answering the question)

Answer (score 3):

The options available to describe why a question was locked are a limited number of choices, and "was devolving into argumentation & off-topic discussions" isn't one of those. But that's what had happened. I cleaned up an edit & some comments that had launched things in that direction, then locked it to prevent further back & forth.

That said, the OP mentioned on another meta thread that he has an update that will calm things down & reduce some of the tendency for things to stray, so it's unlocked now. Hopefully this will be a good conclusion.